# Bootstrap form won't post data into phpmyadmin database

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

My bootstrap form won't post data into the phpmyadmin database, i click submit and nothing is submitted, i have included the configuration file and my form file. The configuration file works with the registration form, so i'm thinking it is to do with my forms. My website is run on hostinger, at www.grademanager.16mb.com . No error messages pop up, when you press submit the page reloads.

**UPDATE :** I have changed the sql statement to a pdo statement, but it will only insert the first two statements, the student name and first subject into my php my admin database. It won't insert the other two statements.

Also how do i make sure it only goes to thte thanks.html file if the data has been submitted successfully ?

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

//set timezone
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

//database credentials
define('DBHOST','mysql.hostinger.co.uk');
define('DBUSER','u717042829_mac');
define('DBPASS','********');
define('DBNAME','u717042829_db1');

//application address
define('DIR','http://grademanager.16mb.com/');
define('SITEEMAIL','noreply@grademanager.comlu.com');

try {

    //create PDO connection 
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";port=3306;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    //show error
    echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    exit;
}

//include the user class, pass in the database connection
include('classes/user.php');
$user = new User($db); 
?>
```

```html
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require("includes/config.php");
//if not logged in redirect to login page
if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ header('Location: login.php'); } 

//define page title
$title = 'Register Past Student';

?>
<html>
 
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Past Student</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  


    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>


<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action= "">

<fieldset>




<!-- Form Name -->
<legend> <a href= "memberpage.php"> Register A Past Student </a> </legend>




<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="name">Student Name</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="First and Last Name" class="form-control input-md" required="">
    
  </div>
</div>

  <div class="form-group">  
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="subject1">Subject 1</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="subject1" name="subject1" class="form-control">
      <option value="Chemistry">Chemistry</option>
      <option value="Computing">Computing</option>
      <option value="Economics">Economics</option>
      <option value="Further Maths">Further Maths</option>
      <option value="Physics">Physics</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Select Basic -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="grade1">Grade 1</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="grade1" name="grade1" class="form-control">
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
      <option value="D">D</option>
      <option value="E">E</option>
      <option value="U">U</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Select Basic -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="subject2">Subject 2</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="subject2" name="subject2" class="form-control">
      <option value="Chemistry">Chemistry</option>
      <option value="Computing">Computing</option>
      <option value="Economics">Economics</option>
      <option value="Further Maths">Further Maths</option>
      <option value="Physics">Physics</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Select Basic -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="grade2">Grade 2</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="grade2" name="grade2" class="form-control">
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
      <option value="D">D</option>
      <option value="E">E</option>
      <option value="U">U</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Select Basic -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="subject3">Subject 3</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="subject3" name="subject3" class="form-control">
      <option value="Chemistry">Chemistry</option>
      <option value="Computing">Computing</option>
      <option value="Economics">Economics</option>
      <option value="Further Maths">Further Maths</option>
      <option value="Physics">Physics</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Select Basic -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="grade3">Grade 3</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="grade3" name="grade3" class="form-control">
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
      <option value="D">D</option>
      <option value="E">E</option>
      <option value="U">U</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Select Basic -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="subject4">Subject 4</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="subject3" name="subject4" class="form-control">
      <option value="Chemistry">Chemistry</option>
      <option value="Computing">Computing</option>
      <option value="Economics">Economics</option>
      <option value="Further Maths">Further Maths</option>
      <option value="Physics">Physics</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="grade4">Grade 4</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="grade1" name="grade4" class="form-control">
      <option value="A">A</option>
      <option value="B">B</option>
      <option value="C">C</option>
      <option value="D">D</option>
      <option value="E">E</option>
      <option value="U">U</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Multiple Radios (inline) -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="attendanc">Attendance %</label>
  <div class="col-md-4"> 
    <label class="radio-inline" for="attendanc-0">
      <input type="radio" name="attendanc" id="attendanc-0" value="99-100" checked="checked">
      99-100
    </label> 
    <label class="radio-inline" for="attendanc-1">
      <input type="radio" name="attendanc" id="attendanc-1" value="97-98">
      97-98
    </label> 
    <label class="radio-inline" for="attendanc-2">
      <input type="radio" name="attendanc" id="attendanc-2" value="95-96">
      95-96
    </label> 
    <label class="radio-inline" for="attendanc-3">
      <input type="radio" name="attendanc" id="attendanc-3" value="">
      93-94
    </label> 
    <label class="radio-inline" for="attendanc-4">
      <input type="radio" name="attendanc" id="attendanc-4" value="">
      91-92
    </label> 
    <label class="radio-inline" for="attendanc-5">
      <input type="radio" name="attendanc" id="attendanc-5" value="">
      90 or less
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Multiple Radios -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="gender">Gender</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="radio">
    <label for="gender-0">
      <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender-0" value="Male" checked="checked">
      Male
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label for="gender-1">
      <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender-1" value="Female">
      Female
    </label>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" id="submit">Click Submit</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button id="singlebutton" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>


<?php 
//require("includes/config.php");


if (isset($_POST['name'])) { //checks if the name has posted value then inserts the data
      $name     = $_POST['name'];
      $subject1 = $_POST['subject1'];
      $grade1   = $_POST['grade1']; 
      $subject2 = $_POST['grade2'];
      $q        = "INSERT INTO paststudent (name, subject1,grade1,subject2) VALUES (:name, :subject1,:grade1,:subject2);"; //sql statement add a colon intead of variables so pdo can prepare the statement and prevent any sql injections 
      $query    = $db ->prepare ($q);
      $results  = $query ->execute (array(  

                ":name" => $name,  //points to the variable 
                ":subject1" => $subject1,
                ":grade1"   => $grade1,
                ":subject2" => $subject2

                



      )); 


              header ('location:thanks.html');

            }


  
?>

</html>
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag:  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and/or check the error logs.

Comment: Simplify your question first. Clarify it's about PHP or MySQL or HTML. BTW, you have two `</form>` in the end.

Comment: First off - have you ensured that you're viewing the page through your web server and PHP is turned on?  i.e. in your address bar, the first word is most likely "localhost" and doesn't include "file://"  Secondly, Jay is right - you need to show your errors.  Let us know what the errors are if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Can you check my answer'

Answer (score 1):

**Error 1:**

You missed `type="submit"`

```
 <button id="singlebutton"  type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button
```

**Error 2:**

> You are mixing all the mysql,mysqli and PDO extensions. Thats why you
>   are not able to insert into db.

In connection file, You have used PDO. And while inserting, You wrote mysqli but your syntax seems to be for mysql.

**Error 3:**

Your insert query syntax is incorrect.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO paststudent (name,subject1,grade,subject2,grade2,subject2,grade2,subject3,grade3,subject4,grade4,attendance,gender) VALUES ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[subject1]','$_POST[grade1]','$_POST[subject2]','$_POST[grade2]','$_POST[subject3]','$_POST[grade3]','$_POST[subject4]','$_POST[grade4]','$_POST[attendance]','$_POST[gender]')";
```

- You have given 13 coumns and 11 values ...???
- Why do you insert the values as is ..???
- Why dont you sanitize it???
- Are you aware of mysql_injections???

Comment: i have changed it to submit, but no data is getting sent to my phpmyadmin database

Comment: hi the mysqli bit has been commented out, so i don't think the mysqli query will effect this ?

Comment: Then how will you insert?

Comment: im not sure how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what effect this will have but I see 2 closing form tags

Answer (score 0):

> - enter space before param and value
> - use mysql_query

```
<?php
     require("includes/config.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO paststudent (name, subject1, grade, subject2, grade2, subject2, grade2, subject3, grade3, subject4, grade4, attendance ,gender) VALUES ('$_POST[name]', '$_POST[subject1]', '$_POST[grade1]', '$_POST[subject2]', '$_POST[grade2]', '$_POST[subject3]', '$_POST[grade3]', '$_POST[subject4]', '$_POST[grade4]', '$_POST[attendance]', '$_POST[gender]')";



    if (mysql_query($sql)) {
        echo "succesfully submitted to the database";
    } else {
        echo "Well this is embarising";
    }


}
?>
```

- if not work ، manually execute insert query to database and check the
  error

Comment: Mysql_ extensions are deprecated... why do you recommend it? And why do you require that space? Have you counted his number of params and values? Have you noticed that his mysql connection is made by PDO and using classes ??? You will get a free down vote...